# Discard all Draft Answers

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I noted with surprise that when I revisited a question, which I *have* answered, apparently the app is still storing my early draft.

I'm concerned that there are quite a number of draft answers left on my phone.

There should be a way to drop all saved 'draft answers' in one go, short of clearing the app's data...

My phone information: Sony Xperia SP running Stock ROM (JB 4.1), rooted.

Comment: I think we should have `revise my draft answers` link instead of discard them all