# Draft answers. Is there an offline editor?

Tags: support, editor, draft

Several people have asked questions about draft answers and, like me, been [surprised to discover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223937/468916) that there is *any* saving of draft answers by Stack Exchange. On the other hand, the answer to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157288/468916) indicates that only one draft answer is ever stored per site.

Like many others, I *discover* what I think *by writing*. Sometimes, I discover that what I think is not worth communicating. Other times, it just takes me time to work out how best to express my ideas. The net result, however, it that I find I want to have several drafts in progress at one time.

Is there any software that I could run on my local machine that would give me the same editor commands as the usual SE editor so that, when the time comes, I can simply copy and paste my answer from my local copy into the SE editor window?

Comment: It’s mostly just markdown. Look up "markdown editor" for a few. Some IDEs, like VS Code, also may have one built in

Comment: Possible duplicates include: [Offline markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287033/offline-markdown-editor), https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195715, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37091

Comment: It is nice that someone has NOW marked this as a duplicate. However, I'd like to suggest that someone with the editing capabaility actually change the title of that duplicate post. In order to find it, one has to know already that it is a markdown editor that is needed! A title such as the one on my own post might be more useful on the original.

Comment: Re *"is any"*: Don't you mean *"isn’t any"*?

Comment: Re *"the same editor commands"*: The same keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: If someone finds your question - they will find that question, which is the point of duplicates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any Markdown-capable editor will do for about 98% of what you care about.

Comment: For the remaining 2%, write the post in Stack Overflow's editor, then when you are ready to save the draft, copy the contents out as plain text and save them into a file. To re-use a saved draft, simply copy the text back into the editor from your file.

Comment: Thanks for the useful reply. I have no idea why the question should attract two almost immediate down votes. The question fits squarely within 'meta' and it isn't a duplicate. It seems that the problem is simply that I should have known the answer to the question already ... and known that there was a named language for the editor ... and known that it was called markdown. Not a great intro to the site! ... except for the very helpful answer!

Comment: Downvotes aren't meant to be a guided tour or introduction to the site, @CrimsonDark. They're just meant to reflect people's aggregated opinion about the quality, clarity, helpfulness, or interestingness of a post. Speculating about why someone downvoted a question, beyond knowing that it was for one of the reasons given in the tooltip on the downvote arrow, is rather a waste of time. If you don't see anything that you can improve about the post, then there's no reason for you to take any action.

Comment: Yes ... I accept that. And if I'd known about the duplicate that has now been highlighted, I wouldn't have posted the question in the first place. But please also see my comment below the question. A title (on the original) that included words like "draft" and "offline" ... perhaps in addition to "markdown" would have meant that an ignoramus like myself would have found it. When one is an expert (at anything) it is very hard to remember, or even imagine, what it was like before the expertise developed.

Comment: I don't think anyone is trying to tell you that you're an ignoramus for not finding that duplicate, or for asking this question, @CrimsonDark. Being able to find questions on Meta sites is one of my dubious superpowers. It helps that over the decade or more that I've been around these sites, I've read most of the questions myself at one point or another. Even the ones I haven't read, I definitely know the keywords to search for. This is the whole reason we *have* a duplicate-marking functionality: it often requires a significant amount of subject-matter expertise to even *find* the dupes!

Comment: Thats not really convenient is it @CodyGray....

Comment: No. There are probably *way* better things for me to have filled my brain with, but here we are. :-)

Comment: Thanks to all. I hadn't realized that duplicates are retained. Now I can see how each duplicate offers a different search-entry point to the original. Thanks again. ... and I have found myself a Markdown editor.